# extract every types of phone number from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
def extract_phone_numbers(string):
    r= re.compile("\+?\d[\( -]?\d{3}[\) -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{2}")
    phone_numbers = re.findall(r, string)
    return phone_numbers
```

It I extract the number like +919835089***, 09835089***, 9835089*** then works fine but when i put +91-9835089*** it print 1-9835089***

Comment: Your first `\d` is literally just that. Maybe you meant `\d{2}?` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `*` (one or more) after first `\d`

```
string = "+91983508233, 09835089456, 9835089555, +91-9835089444"
r= re.compile("\+?\d*[\( -]?\d{3}[\) -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{2}")
phone_numbers = re.findall(r, string)
print(phone_numbers)

['+91983508233', ' 0983508945', ' 9835089555', '+91-9835089444']
```